# kivy gridlayout, stop dynamic resizing of children

Tags: python, kivy, grid-layout

I have a grid layout containing a variable amount of children.
n1...n∞, I can never predict how many children the grid will contain.

Kivy, rather annoyingly makes the children smaller and smaller in relation to the amount of children in the grid. for example:

```
layout2 = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint_y=(3))
    layout2.bind(minimum_height=layout2.setter('height'))
```

this size is fine when the grid contains around 6 children, however when it contains say 20, the images are tiny.

How can I stop kivy resizing?

Answers in Python please.

Comment: So you want a ScrollView ?

Comment: I already have a scroll view, sorry forgot to say

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make size_hint_y depend on the row count, So it may look like this in a KV file

```
ScrollView:
    MyGrid:
        size_hint_y: self.rows / 10.0 + 1.0 #you should play with this a bit ...
```

Comment: can you explain 'rows', i know its in the grid layout api but for me it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try `size_hint=None`

```
layout2 = GridLayout(cols=2, size_hint_y=None)
```

Comment: this makes the images super small